# Web SQL Database DateTime Field comparison

Tags: javascript, datetime, web-sql

I have a web sql database table with two DateTime fields in it.  I'm getting 0 rows when I issue the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM State WHERE LastModified > LastUploaded
```

But I can see in the resources tab in Chrome Inspector that there is a row where LastModified is greater than LastUploaded.

I guess I don't know what I'm even dealing with.  What book should I read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this :

SELECT * FROM state WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastModified) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LastUploaded)

Best regards :)